# Appending arguments to url with Java

Tags: java

I am using the following method to add url encoded (the encoding occurs inside another method) name/value pairs to the end of a url represented by the variable mUrl using the following code

```
 public void addArgument(String name, String value){

        String encName = urlEncode ( name ) ;

        String encValue = urlEncode( value ) ;

        String urlenc;

        if ( argCount++ == 0 ){

            urlenc = "?" + encName + "=" + encValue + "&";

            mUrl = mUrl + urlenc;

            argCount++;

        } else {

            urlenc = encName + "=" + encValue + "&";  

            mUrl = mUrl + urlenc;
       }

    }
```

The code works fine however the resulting url ends in "&". For example:

http://www.amazon.com?name=sam&age=5&

Is there a way I can adjust my code to get rid of the "&" on the end of the url?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked up how to remove the last character in a String?

Comment: I will do that now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `&` at the beginning instead of at the end:

```
public void addArgument(String name, String value) {
    mUrl += (argCount++ == 0 ? "?" : "&") + urlEncode(name) + "=" + urlEncode(value);
}
```